# In Inspect.exe tool Automation IDs are missing for text elements for an .net webview2 app angular 15 desktop app

Tags: angular, ui-automation, pywinauto, inspect.exe

we have a .net webview2 app angular 15 desktop app
and we have simple text elements such as span/labels etc which have an id attribute in angular templates and these appear as UIA_TextControlTypeId in inspect.exe tool (windows sdk).  However the automation ids do not appear for these in the tool.

All other elements such as button/input/table td elements etc with the id attribute do show up in inspect.exe tool, is this expected?
for e.g. the following do not get the automation ids

```
<span id="username">{{name}}</span>
<label id="about-label">About</label>
```

but the following do show up with ids

```
<input id="user-email" type="text"/>
<button id="home"/>
```